# How can you determine the location of the git-core folder dynamically?

Tags: git

A quick google says that the folder should be located at `/usr/share/git-core` but I think this differs depending on the way it was installed since mine is located at `/usr/local/share/git-core` and my colleague's is somewhere else.

Is there a command or variable available to output the absolute location of `git-core`?

Comment: `find` command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$ git --exec-path
/usr/lib/git-core
```

Overridable via an argument to that flag or with GIT_EXEC_PATH environment variable.

If you have multiple copies of git, then try `~/homebrew/bin/git` or `/usr/bin/git` or whatever the path to Xcode's copy is.

The full story of how git finds subcommands is actually straightforward: It finds the value of exec_path -- either from argv, the environment, or the compile-time value. Then it pushes this onto the front of PATH.

```
/*
 * We use PATH to find git commands, but we prepend some higher
 * precedence paths: the "--exec-path" option, the GIT_EXEC_PATH
 * environment, and the $(gitexecdir) from the Makefile at build
 * time.
 */
setup_path();
```

(Contrary to what this comment implies, it just picks one of those.)

Much older versions of git just polluted your path with all the git-whatever commands.

If you're trying to diagnose or bandage something funky, you could try manipulating PATH with whatever the correct path to git-core is, but it's much more likely that invoking the correct copy of git will work.

```
$ echo '/usr/bin/env' > ~/local/bin/git-env
$ chmod +x ~/local/bin/git-env
$ env - PATH=~/local/bin /usr/bin/git env
PATH=/usr/lib/git-core:/home/josh/local/bin
PWD=/home/josh
$
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's interesting, there seems to be more than one `git-core` since when I run that command I get

    /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.9.2/libexec/git-core

but there's also my `git-core` at `/usr/local/share/git-core`.

They seem different, too - the one from the exec path contains all the commands while the one I'm after contains just `contrib` and `templates`. 

Do you know if there's a command to get to the other one?

Comment: Maybe one is homebrew's symlink into the Cellar?

Comment: Doh that's exactly it. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkStickley Wow, that tripped me up too. But the symlink points to `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.9.2/`**`share`**`/git-core`, and I can't tell what that's actually used for. It's extremely confusing.